# Docker installation on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am new here and I've been trying to install docker on Ubuntu but I have no clue where this error is coming from.

I followed the installation instruction for Ubuntu on Docker website, and everything is installed, except that running docker gives me an error message that says "docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'."

This is Ubuntu Bionix 18.04, and my laptop runs on Windows. 
I tried running docker with "sudo service docker restart", but when I check the status with "sudo service docker status" after the restart command, it says Docker is not running.

```
    msok0216@DESKTOP-3M5NTKP:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service docker restart
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                       [ OK ]
msok0216@DESKTOP-3M5NTKP:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
msok0216@DESKTOP-3M5NTKP:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
msok0216@DESKTOP-3M5NTKP:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is running
msok0216@DESKTOP-3M5NTKP:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOiqw.png)

Comment: did you checked logs ? you must get something more specific in the logs.

Comment: what's the output of docker ps or docker info? I'm by no means of an expert but they may help or maybe systemctl start docker. This thread may help https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32658

Comment: Can be a pain to get docker to run on Ubuntu at times - can you try: sudo systemctl start docker ?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying enough. This is Ubuntu WSL and it doesn't seem to support systemctl command @RobScully